# How long does it take for Facebook to verify a new account?

Tags: facebook, account-management, facebook-privacy, facebook-account

I made a Facebook account for mom on April 24th and on the same day it got disabled. I used the same name, surname and birthday that is in her ID. The next day (25th of April) I saw that they were verifying account.

After some days I tried to log into that account, but it said that *if you think your account was disabled, please visit the Help Center*. I sent my mom's ID and after that I got no email on mom's gmail from Facebook. Last week I sent mom's ID once again and still no answer from them and still after trying to log in it shows the same message box.

[image]

I understand that now is quarantine, but should I wait for their response for weeks or months? Or try to make a new account?